# Issues with simple mean calculator

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
//Make sure there is an argv[1] to check
if (1 < argc) {
    std::string option = std::string(argv[1]);
    if ("mean" == option) {
        float sum = 0;
        cout << (argc)<<"\n";
        for (int i = 0; i<= argc; i++){
        sum = sum+reinterpret_cast<int>(argv[i]);

        }
        cout<<(sum)<<"\n";
        cout<<(argc)<<"\n";
        cout<<(sum/argc)<<"\n";
    }
return 0
}
```

I'm new to c++, but this code is returning ludicrous values for what I am inputing.  For example, I use the command line "homework1 mean 1 2 3 4" and the values are in the quadrillions.  I am using a 64 bit machine if that helps, I'm new to c++ so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` will not convert a string into an integer...

Comment: A homework question showing reasonable amount of own work, wow. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `reinterpret_cast` will not convert string into integer. Use something like `std::stod`. (Depends on how much error checking you want to do.)

Second, these bounds

```
for (int i = 0; i<= argc; i++)
```

will not work, because argv[0] is name of the executable and argv[argc] is a null pointer. Use

```
for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++){
    sum += std::stof(argv[i]);
}
```

Note, your compiler needs to have support for c++11 for this to work. ([`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and such have been added in the c++11 revision of the standard.) If it doesn't you will need to use `sum += strtof(argv[i], NULL);`. For more details see [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) for `strtof`.

Comment: Sorry your right, I had it at i=1 before, I was trying to see how sum and argc were changing (I just learned what argc meant like 10 minutes ago) as the program was running.  Also, could you show me the syntax for std::stod?  would I just write std::stod(argv[i])?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've actually used the atof function, it works now.  Thanks everybody else as well. I'm quite used to java but c++ seems to be extremely similar so far.

Comment: @user3081246 You will want to get into habit of using different family of functions than `atof`, `atoi`, etc, because their error checking is really bad (actually, non-existant), while `strtof` and `stof` will actually let you do at least some.

Comment: I'll need to update my compiler, but I have to use g++ specifically to turn in my assignments.  Not sure what to do about that